# LISP File I/O - Extract and Convert Information

Tags: common-lisp

I have a file (furniture.lisp) that looks basically like this (with many more entries):

```
(addgv :furniture 'stove
  (make-instance 'stove
    :pose (tf:make-pose-stamped
            "map"                         ; frame-id
            0.0
            (tf:make-3d-vector -3.1 -0.9 0)     ; translation/origin
            (tf:euler->quaternion :az 0))))

(addgv :furniture 'drawers-cupboard
  (make-instance 'cupboard
    :pose (tf:make-pose-stamped
            "map"
            0.0
            (tf:make-3d-vector -3.1 0.1 0)
            (tf:euler->quaternion :az 0))))
```

Now, I'd like to have a function `(get-locations "furniture.lisp" "locations.txt")` that extracts the objects coordinates in the 3d-vector and writes its output to a file:

```
(location stove -3.1 -0.9 9)
(location drawers-cupboard -3.1 0.1 0)
...
```

I started by writing an expression that reads in the file (so far without parametrization) line by line:

```
(ql:quickload "split-sequence")

(with-open-file (stream "furniture.lisp")
(do ((line (read-line stream nil)
           (read-line stream nil)))
    ((null line))
    (princ (split-sequence::split-sequence #\Space line)) ; Just for demonstration
 ))
```

But I realized that I have no chance/idea to "connect" the name of the object (e.g. stove) and its coordinates. I'd need the second symbol after "(addgv " for the name and variable "distance of words" for the coordinates. So I tried to read the file into one big list:

```
(defun make-list-from-text (fn)
  (with-open-file (stream fn)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
          while line
          collect
               (split-sequence::split-sequence #\Space line))))
```

Whereby every line is a sublist (I don't know if this substructure is a advantage, perhaps I should 'flatten' the result). Now I'm stuck. Furthermore, I have the feeling, that my approach is somehow inelegant.

**EDIT:**

I followed Svante's approach and finally got the desired output! Besides creating a dummy package, I also had to create dummy exports for the package (e.g. `:export :make-3d-vector`). Additionally,`:key #'car` did not work, as my list was a 'mixed' list, consisting of sublists (e.g. `(make-instance ...)`) and symbols (e.g. `addgv`). So I created a helper function:

```
(defun find-helper (list-or-symbol)
    (if (listp list-or-symbol)
       (car list-or-symbol)
        list-or-symbol))
```

And replaced `#'car` by `#'find-helper`.

Comment: I don't know what `addgv` or some of the other functions do, but ... would it help if the file began with `(defvar the-furniture (list` and ended with an extra `)`?  Then you can just read in the file all at once, and iterate through `the-furniture` using whatever means you like--`map`, `dolist`, etc.  That separates out the file-reading issues from the issue of how to parse out what you want from each entry.

Comment: In this case, I get the error: `there is no package with name "TF" (I don't have the packages, as I just would need the coordinates). Furthermore, I'd be interested in a general way of doing this (e.g if the source file has 'bad syntax' or no LISP compatible style at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea would be to create a dummy `tf` package, then `read` the forms and parse whatever you need from them.  Something like this (untested):

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (unless (find-package #:tf)
    (defpackage #:tf)))

(defun extract-location-file ()
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
    (with-open-file (in "furniture.lisp")
      (with-open-file (out "locations.txt"
                           :direction :output
                           :if-exists :supersede
                           :if-does-not-exist :create)
        (loop :for form := (read in nil)
              :while form
              :do (print (extract-location form) out)
                  (terpri)))))

(defun extract-location (form)
  `(location ,(third form)
             ,@(rest (find 'tf::make-3d-vector
                           (find 'tf::make-pose-stamped
                                 (find 'make-instance
                                       form
                                       :key #'car)
                                 :key #'car)
                           :key #'car))))
```

Be sure not to omit to bind `*read-eval*` to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

The general way would be:

1. read the whole file as string (see [here](https://github.com/vseloved/rutils/blob/master/core/string.lisp#L31))
2. `(cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "tf::?" content "")`, i.e. replace all references to package `tf` to avoid package-related errors
3. put `'()` around the contents
4. `read` it and assign to a variable
5. now you have structured data that you can process using various list-manipulating functions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this would be a non-portable solution:

- handle the reader error
- do what is necessary to fix the problem
- continue

For example in LispWorks I could do something like this (just a sketch):

```
CL-USER 60 > (defun test ()
               (handler-bind ((conditions:package-not-found-reader
                               (lambda (c)
                                 (continue c)))
                              (conditions:simple-reader-error
                               (lambda (c)
                                 (continue c))))
                     (read-from-string "'(foo27:bar19 bar18:foo44)")))
TEST

CL-USER 61 > (test)
(QUOTE (FOO27::BAR19 BAR18::FOO44))
```

It calls the *continue* restarts for the missing package error and then for the error that the symbol is not exported. The restarts create the package and the other one is returning a non-exported symbol...